# JavaScript: Sending POST, redirecting to response

Tags: javascript, http, post, redirect

I have an image with an onclick. When the click event fires, I want to send an HTTP POST and have the window.location redirect to the response to the POST. How can I do that?

Answer (score 16):

Just bind the button to the submit method of a form element, and the redirect will happen naturally.

```
<script type='text/javascript'>
 function form_send(){
   f=document.getElementById('the_form');
   if(f){
     f.submit();
     }
   }
 </script>

<form method='post' action='your_post_url.html' id='the_form'>
  <input type='hidden' value='whatever'>
</form>

<span id='subm' onclick='form_send()'>Submit</span>
```

Comment: That doesn't handle getting a redirect address from the response body.

Comment: Aha, I missed that part of the question. It could have been phrased more clearly.

Comment: I agree with the slight ambiguity of the question. I'm not even sure my answer is addressing the question properly, even though it received 3 up-votes. (+1 to compensate for the downvotes)

Comment: Thanks Daniel; I initially wondered why you were suggesting to use an XHR for this but upon re-reading it, I do think that's what the asker intended, to get a location as a response from the POST and go there and therefore it requires an XHR. I get the feeling it could be solved in other ways, though, if the asker supplied more details.

Answer (score 13):

Assuming you require to send the POST request asynchronously, you may want to check the example below to get you going in the right direction:

```
<img src="my_image.png" onClick="postOnClick();">
```

Then you require a JavaScript function that submits an asynchronous HTTP POST request and redirects the browser to a URL received from the HTTP response. You should be able to use `XMLHttpRequest` for such an asynchronous call, as in the following example:

```
function postOnClick()
{
    var http = new XMLHttpRequest();

    var params = "arg1=value1&arg2=value2";

    http.open("POST", "post_data.php", true);

    http.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
    http.setRequestHeader("Content-length", params.length);
    http.setRequestHeader("Connection", "close");

    http.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if (http.readyState == 4 && http.status == 200) {
            window.location = http.responseText;
        }
    }

    http.send(params);
}
```

Note that for a truly cross-browser `XMLHttpRequest` call, you may want to use a standard-compliant cross-browser XMLHttpRequest implementation like [XMLHttpRequest.js](http://code.google.com/p/xmlhttprequest/), unless you are using some JavaScript framework like [jQuery](http://jquery.com), [Prototype](http://www.prototypejs.org/), [YUI](http://developer.yahoo.com/yui/), [ExtJS](http://extjs.com), et al.

In addition, also note that the above will only work if you are posting to a script hosted within the same domain, otherwise you will be violating the [same-origin policy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy) and modern web browsers will refuse to send the request.

Comment: This doesn't work. http.responseText is the body of the HTML document (post_data.php). You can't redirect to an HTML string.

Comment: @JamesBrownIsDead: It depends on what you return from your server-side script. If you return simple plain text, `http.responseText` will hold just the URL. Is there a particular reason why your script is returning HTML?

Answer (score 3):

Instead of `window.location = http.responseText` use the following:

```
http.onreadystatechange = function() {
  if (http.readyState == 4 && http.status == 200) {
    document.open();
    document.write(http.responseText);
  }
}
```

`document.open()` clears the current content of the page and `document.write()` inserts the response html code into your page.

Answer (score 3):

You could use this function i made:

```
function redirect_by_post(purl, pparameters, in_new_tab) {
    pparameters = (typeof pparameters == 'undefined') ? {} : pparameters;
    in_new_tab = (typeof in_new_tab == 'undefined') ? true : in_new_tab;

    var form = document.createElement("form");
    $(form).attr("id", "reg-form").attr("name", "reg-form").attr("action", purl).attr("method", "post").attr("enctype", "multipart/form-data");
    if (in_new_tab) {
        $(form).attr("target", "_blank");
    }
    $.each(pparameters, function(key) {
        $(form).append('<input type="text" name="' + key + '" value="' + this + '" />');
    });
    document.body.appendChild(form);
    form.submit();
    document.body.removeChild(form);

    return false;
}

$('#btn').button().click(function() {
    redirect_by_post('http://pamppi.info/jotform-testing/thankyou/postvars.php', {
        variable1: 'Carlos',
        variable2: 'Garcia'
    }, true);
});
```

Comment: Would be better if you paste here your code to see and discuses about it.

Answer (score 2):

Using [jQuery](http://www.jquery.com) post the data and redirect to your desired location like so:

```
$.ajax({
  type: 'POST',
  url: 'receivedata.asp',
  data: 'formValue=someValue',
  success: function(data){
      window.location = data;
  }
});
```

You could remove the `data: 'formValue=someValue',` if there is no data to pass to the page you want to post to.

Comment: Doesn't work as expected. 'data' retrieves the request's response, in this case the file 'receivedata.asp' and not a url.

Answer (score 1):

Use a input type image.

```
<form action="someUrl.html" method="POST">
    <input type="image" src="img.png" width="30" height="30" alt="Submit">
</form>
```

When clicking on the image you will be redirected to "someUrl.html" and a post will be sent to it